# How to maximize min.entropy from a bounded log normal distribution?

Tags: lognormal-distribution, entropy

**Background:**
I have random source that can be measured and histogrammed over many samples as:

[image: histogram]

My measuring instrument can only measure a fixed range of $0 -1023$, so that axis must always stay the same.  All samples are discrete integer values.  I have full control over the mean and standard deviation of the samples, so that I can spread out the distribution.  I can spread it out so far that it would exceed a reading of $1023$.  So I might have the following, where $V_{max} = 1023$:

[image: stretched histogram]

You can see that the missing part of the distribution exceeds the allowable range and it's samples just pile up in the blue bar at $V_{max}$.  As I stretch the standard deviation further, $P(V_{max})$ increases and $P(V_{mode})$, yellow bar,  decreases.

`min.entropy` is defined to be $H = -log(P_{max})$, where $P_{max}$ is the most likely value in a distribution.

**Question:** What shape would the histogram have to be to maximize $H$?

I think that there has to be a sweet spot somewhere during scaling of the standard deviation.  I suspect that H is maximal when $P(V_{mode}) = P(V_{max})$ but I'm not sure.  This means the yellow and blue bars would be identical heights. So achieving something like this:

$$H_{max} = -\log \left( \min\left.\begin{cases}\max(P_v) & 0 \le v < V_{max} \\ P_v & v=V_{max} \end{cases} \right\} \right)$$

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by saying that the samples are log-normal but are all discrete integer values?  I'm not trying to be pedantic--in this case, the answer depends substantially on what you mean here.  For example, you might mean that the PMF of your discrete-valued distribution is proportional to the PDF of the lognormal evaluated at the integers.  Or you might take every sample and round it to the nearest value.  Or...

Comment: @user43849   Well the shape of the histogram is log normalish.  I don't know what else to call it.  Yes the samples are discrete integers, but look at the shape.  There was no rounding, these are integer samples of a fluctuating voltage level.

Comment: But the values of mu and sd that maximize H depend on what the actual distribution is.

Comment: @user43849 It's that shape as plotted.  That's empirical data from a 10 bit A to D converter setup on my bench.  The literature for this experiment calls it log normal.  It's avalanche breakdown noise on a 24V zener diode which is consistent with a normal * normal * normal * normal... distribution.  Remember that this question relates to min. entropy not Shannon entropy.

Comment: Well if the distribution is "log-normalish" enough, then for any value of the standard deviation, P(vmax) is monotonically increasing with the mean and P(vmode) is monotonically decreasing with the mean.  So it's clear that H will be maximized when P(vmax)=P(vmode).  If we knew the specifics of the distribution, we could find the standard deviation that actually maximizes H.  But knowing that it looks roughly like the picture and roughly like a log-normal (that is discretized somehow) isn't enough to actually do the optimization.

Comment: @user43849  You seem to be suggesting the answer lies at P(vmax)=P(vmode).  If you convert your comment, I'll accept :-)

Comment: Cool--I think the answer below pretty much covers all the bases.

Comment: This is a puzzling question because it seems to have nothing to do with the entropy of anything.  Entropies are always log probabilities *times* those probabilities.  Are you sure you are asking the question you intended to ask?

Comment: @whuber Absolutely.  I've had to ask it on 3 (or 4 I forget now) SE sites to get an answer so I realise that it's a hard question.  For the umpteenth time, information entropy is measured in bits /sample.  So for example it might be 3.7 bits /sample.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory#Entropy_of_an_information_source is an appropriate introduction.

Comment: In the linked wikipedia article, H is measured exactly as @whuber describes.  (p times log(p)).

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not asking for an introduction.  I am trying to draw your attention to the fact that what you call an "entropy" is not actually an entropy.  As you have asked it it's actually a very easy question, but if it were actually a question about how to maximize the *true* (conventional) entropy of this censored lognormal distribution then the only solution available to you is numerical maximization--and the solution is quite different (the probability in the largest bin would be by far the largest of all the probabilities).

Comment: @whuber but it seems to me that since the answer occurs where two bins hold equal probability mass, the factor of p doesn't actually change the solution, no?  Note that the OP doesn't want to maximize the entropy of the distribution, but just (apparently) the minimum entropy associated with any single integer value.

Comment: @user43849 Using the correct formula for entropy *profoundly* changes the answer. The way to maximize entropy (*i.e.*, negative expected log probability) is to spread the distribution as evenly as possible.  The two spikes from the mode and the right hand bin give a very uneven distribution, so in fact the entropy becomes substantially greater by flattening out the distribution in the first 1023 bins, at a price of (greatly) increasing the height of the 1024th bin.  Although it's not difficult to find the maximum entropy (there are only two parameters to vary), there's no closed form solution.

Comment: @whuber sorry, you posted just as I edited my comment. Note that the OP doesn't want to maximize the entropy of the distribution, but just (apparently) the minimum contribution to entropy associated with any single integer value.

Comment: @user43849 That is precisely what I'm trying to ascertain.  If he really is interested in entropy, then he has formulated his problem incorrectly and will suffer from a grossly inferior solution; but if he is not interested in entropy (as it's known by the rest of the world) then it would help all future readers to remove the references to entropy, lest it be confusing.  Either way, there is something we need to find out and correct if we can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56270/discussion-between-user43849-and-whuber).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is valid for $H$ as defined by the OP. It is also valid for $H=p\ln{p}$, because the solution will still occur where $P(V_{mode})=P(V_{max})$, the factor of $p$ will drop out.

This answer assumes that the discrete (integer-valued) distribution in the question is "similar enough" to a log-normal that the following two approximations are valid:

1. $P(V_{mode})$ is proportional to the probability density at the mode of the log-normal.
2. $P(V_{max})$ is proportional to the probability mass of the log normal that lies to the right of $V_{max}$

Therefore, with (positive) proportionality constants ($\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$), we have that 
$$P(V_{mode})=\alpha_1 \frac{e^{-\frac{(\ln{(e^{\mu-\sigma^2})} - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{e^{\mu-\sigma^2}\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}=
\alpha_1 \frac{e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}-\mu}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}$$ and 
$$P(V_{max})=\alpha_2\left[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{\ln{(V_{max})}-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma} \right)\right]$$
where erf is the error function (the first equation comes from plugging in the mode of the lognormal to the PDF for the log normal, and the second comes from plugging in $V_{max}$ to one minus the CDF of the log-normal).

Note that for any value of $\sigma$, $P(V_{mode})$ monotonically decreases in $\mu$.  Also note that the erf is monotonically increasing, so for any value of $\sigma$, $P(V_{max})$ is monotonically increasing in $\mu$.

Note further that $P_{max}$ occurs either at $P(V_{mode})$ or at $P(V_{max})$. So for any value of $\sigma$, we maximize $H$ by varying $\mu$ until $P(V_{mode})=P(V_{max})$. At this value of $\mu$, increasing $\mu$ would increase $P(V_{max})$ and decreasing $\mu$ would increase $P(V_{mode})$.

Thus, it is certainly the case that $H$ is maximized where $P(V_{mode})=P(V_{max})$.

Furthermore, given the constraint $P(V_{mode})=P(V_{max})$ (and $\sigma >= 0$), it is possible to pick a value of $\sigma$ that maximizes $H$.  This optimization problem could be solved numerically if it were possible to write down the actual probability mass function for this discrete "log-normalish" distribution.

Comment: I can easily measure σ and μ for the posted chart by rerunning the experiment and simply tallying the individual samples.  I didn't post these though as I can't control them directly. All I can do is change a couple of resistors which are statistically uselessly measured in Ohms.  Hence the graphical solution.